# my swap function is not working in python

Tags: python, list

please guys, this function is meant to swap a group of items in a list, like the first k items with the last k items, but I dont know how to get the function to work

```
 def swap(L, k):
     L[len(L)-k:], L[:k] = L[:k], L[len(L)-k:]
```

yet when I run this with doctest, it fails

```
swap([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],2)
```

Comment: How do you know that it fails? You swap the elements in-place then discard the list.

Comment: your code doesn't fail, it's working `t=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]; swap(t,2); print(t)`

Comment: you forgot to return L

Comment: @TeejayBruno Modifying the argument **and** returning it is not the best practice. Built-in methods such as `.sort()` don't do that either.

Comment: What exactly is failing? This code works exactly how it is supposed to (assuming you wanted to modify the list `L` in-place).

Comment: What are you testing with doctest exactly? There are no prompts (`>>>`) in your code, so no doctests per se.

Comment: This is what am testing with do test

Answer (score 0):

Fix the indexes, return a list from the method, and print the resulting list:

```
def swap(L, k):
     return L[(-k):] + L[k:(-k)] + L[:k]

lst = swap([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2)
print(lst)     
# [5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Note that the original list is not modified - what is returned is a *different* list with elements swapped.

Comment: The parens around `-k` are also redundant

Comment: @wjandrea Parens around `-k` are not necessary. I added them for readability.

Answer (score 0):

The function works perfectly, but you have no other references to the list you're passing in, so it gets discarded. Simply save the list to a name before passing it in.

By the way, the `len(L)` is unnecessary.

```
def swap(L, k):
    """
    >>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    >>> swap(lst, 2)
    >>> lst
    [5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2]
    """
    L[-k:], L[:k] = L[:k], L[-k:]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def swap(L, k):
   J = L[:k]
   L[:k] = L[-2:]
   L[-2:] = J
```

```
P = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
swap(P,2)
# P ==[5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2]
```